# Why the input field is starting from center of the field?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The intitial position of cursor is at center of the field. How to make it to top left?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">    
</head>
<body style="background-color: cadetblue; height:1000px">
<form>
   <input type="text" class="notes-input" name="note">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
.notes-input {
    width: 50%;
    line-height: 8em;
    margin:50px 0px 0px 150px ;
}
```

Comment: You have given 50px as left margin in your css, and the line-height: 8em; that is why. Reduce that line height to get your cursor towards top left.

Comment: This is the  default behavior of input. Your expected behaviour can be achieved using textarea.

Comment: Even if a textarea is used, the line-height in the style must be reduced, if it is as high as 8em, then the multiline text will have huge whitespace gap between each line.

Comment: use `textarea` instead of input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use textarea instead of input

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">    
</head>
<style>
.notes-input {
    width: 50%;
    margin:50px 0px 0px 150px ;
}
</style>
<body style="background-color: cadetblue; height:1000px">
<form>
   <textarea type="text" rows="5" class="notes-input" name="note"></textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

if we want only input and box size should be big means we can use the below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">    
</head>
<style>
.notes-input {
    width: 50%;
    margin:50px 0px 0px 150px ;
    padding-bottom:150px;

}
</style>
<body style="background-color: cadetblue; height:1000px">
<form>
   <input type="text" class="notes-input" name="note">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You do not answer the question, you propose an alternative. You should only do this if you have explained why the alternative is necessary.

Comment: with input field we can enter only one line of text.  if we want to use multi line text means textarea is the best option. else if we want only input with huge box size means we can remove line-height and add padding-bottom to the input field...

Comment: Thanks for adding details, you can edit your answer to add these info in your answer. This will be helpful for the community :)

Comment: thanks. I think i should use textarea

Answer (score 0):

use `textarea` instead of input.

```html
<textarea name="textarea" style="width:250px;height:150px;"></textarea>
```